# android - How to make a bottom sheet from bottom to top

Tags: android

i was wondering how can I make something like  this ,I've no idea how can I do this . 
as you can see in this picture :

[image]

and when we click or drag the bottom part, it opens like this :

[image]

I really have no idea have can I do something like this.

Comment: have a look https://android-arsenal.com/tag/138

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library from GitHub: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 1):

Google introduced [Bottom Sheets](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) in Support library 23.2.0 which is propably exactly what you want.